# Taking a snapshot of a sequence/pattern query in Siddhi

Tags: complex-event-processing, siddhi

I am currently working on a mechanism to extract the intermediate states of CEP queries, so that I can use this information to restore the query state at a later point in time (for example, after node failure).

Extracing intermediate state works fine for window-based (e.g., timeBatch query) or aggregate-based queries (e.g., sum), given that I can create a custom window/aggregate function and extract the intermediate state (for example, the current events in the window or the current sum).

Even for a sequence/pattern query, I can see how extracting the intermediate state can be useful for restoration purposes. For example, if I have a pattern query where I look for A -> B -> C, and so far, A -> B has already been recognised, I can try extracting this sub-pattern as part of a query snapshot. Later, upon restoration, I only need to search for the events of type C to satisfy the pattern.

So far, I have not come across a viable approach of extracting this information. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can go about this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can start by referring to [SnapshotService](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/master/modules/siddhi-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/util/snapshot/SnapshotService.java), which can be used to get the current serialized states of queries.

Comment: So, I did some reading on that as well as the [persistence store](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/master/modules/siddhi-core/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/managment/PersistenceTestCase.java). It seems like I can obtain partial sequence/pattern states by storing a snapshot of the corresponding `AppRunTime`. Would you possibly know the exact class where this snapshot for a pattern is generated?

Comment: Refer to classes which implements Snapshotable within `org.wso2.siddhi.core.query.input.stream.state` package. Link: https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/tree/master/modules/siddhi-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/query/input/stream/state